# Importing files back and forth in python

Tags: python, tkinter, import

I am new to python, this is my first question here so let me know if something is missing from the question. I am trying to create a script that takes input from the user in one file, does some calculations in another file and then presents the calculated result.

To gather input I am using tkinter and based on the selection in the tkinter window I wish to run another file that takes the input and computes the calculations.

**Code examples:**

**Input file:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
var = 0
def var1():
    global var
    var = entry1.get()

def store(): 
    var1()

entry1 = tk.Entry()
Label1 = tk.Label(root, text="Entry 1")
Label1.grid(row=3, column=0)
entry1.grid(row=3, column=1)

#dropdown menu
clicked = tk.StringVar()
clicked.set("Choose from dropdown menu")
options = ["1", "2"]
transport = tk.OptionMenu( root , clicked , *options)
transport.grid(row=4, column=1)

def dropdown_menu():
    if clicked.get() =="1":
        print("You chose 1")
        import file1
    if clicked.get() =="2":
       import file2

submit = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", width=10, command=store)
submit.grid(row=5, column = 1)
btn = tk.Button(root, text="Confirm", command=dropdown_menu)
btn.grid(row= 5, column= 2)

root.mainloop()
```

**Calculation file:**

```
import inputfile as inp

var1 = inp.var1()
print(var1)
print("file1 is running") #added test to see if the program runs
```

The problem is that I am importing the first file (the input file) into the second file (calculation file) to get the correct input for the calculations, but I also import the calculation file into the input file to get it to run, so then another tkinter window opens, I assume it is because I am first running the input file, then the calculation file which calls the input file again.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

**Edit to add information**
Thank you for your comments, so yes, I am definitely in a sort of loop. I edited the code here to make it more complete. When I run it I get the following window, where I add something into Entry1 and choose 1 or 2 from the dropdown - I can then confirm the dropdown menu choice with the Confirm button.
[Pop-up tkinter window for input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpOal.png)
When I confirm, the code line

```
import inputfile as inp
```

runs which makes another input window open (where I cannot input any new information tough).

[New pop-up window that opens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI7YS.png)

I want to be able to get the information from the input file without running it again in the calculation file.

Comment: I sounds to me like you have created a circular import?

Comment: Could you add an example of how you execute the code?

Comment: it's preferred that you don't use "input" as an alias for your imports because it's a built-in function...

Comment: you should also realize that when the import line is executed all the code in the "input" is run. So it is running itself in the case that is described in the question (potential infinite loop.

Comment: It is better to move the code of a module inside a class or function in that module.  You can also pass required arguments to this class or function instead of accessing them directly (which may not work) in the module.